# Navigation bar in showAsset(.photoLibrary, withTag:button.tag) always disappear after I take a picture using showAsset(.camera, withTag:button.tag)

Tags: ios, swift

When I open the photoGallery first, it always have the "cancel" and "back" button in the navigation bar. But everytime after I took a picture using "showAsset(.camera, withTag:button.tag)", then use the photoGallery, the buttons in the navigation bar disappears.

```
extension FormTableView:DynamicInventorySheetViewDelegate {

func inventorySheet(inventorySheet: DynamicInventorySheetView, withMediaButton button: MaterialButton) {
    print("should open picker")

    let options = ActionSheet(backgroundColor: .white)
    options.showActionSheet()

    options.addAction(action: CustomButton(#imageLiteral(resourceName: "icon_camera"),
                                           withTitle: "action_take_photo".localized(),
                                           withButtonType: .normal,
                                           withActionHandler: { [weak self] in

                                            guard let this = self else { return }                                               this.parent?.isTableField = true
                                            this.parent?.showAsset(.camera, withTag:button.tag)

    }))

    options.addAction(action: CustomButton(#imageLiteral(resourceName: "add_photo"),
                                           withTitle: "action_upload_gallery".localized(),
                                           withButtonType: .normal,
                                           withActionHandler: { [weak self] in

                                            guard let this = self else { return }

                                            this.parent?.isTableField = true
                                            print("\(button.tag)")
                                            this.parent?.showAsset(.photoLibrary, withTag:button.tag)

    }))

    options.addAction(action: CustomButton(#imageLiteral(resourceName: "ic_close"),
                                           withTitle: "action_cancel".localized(),
                                           withButtonType: .normal,
                                           withActionHandler: {

    }))
}
```

}

this is the UIImagePickerDelegate:

```
fileprivate lazy var imagePickerController: UIImagePickerController = {

    let imagePickerController = UIImagePickerController()
    imagePickerController.delegate = formTableView?.parent

    return imagePickerController
}()


func showAsset(_ type: UIImagePickerController.SourceType, withTag tag: Int) {

    imagePickerController.view.tag = tag
    imagePickerController.sourceType = type
    formTableView?.parent?.present(imagePickerController, animated:true) {

    }

}
```

Comment: Where are you setting the UIImagePickerController?

Comment: I edited the post. All of the code is inside of the file formMediaTableviewCell

Comment: I don't know if it's a bug or not, but for some reason, you cannot reuse the imagePickerController for photoLibrary after using it for camera. Whenever you get ready to use it for photoLibrary, create a new instance: `imagePickerController = UIImagePickerController()`. Set the delegate again, as well.

Comment: IT WORKED!! thank you so much...